# Optimisation of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am not an expert in SQL Server,
I have one table MainRBDBalance and another RBDTransaction:

```
CREATE TABLE [hybarmoney].[MAINRBDBALANCE]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USERID] [bigint] NULL,
    [RBD] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [CurrentDollar] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [EquivalentRBD] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [UpdatedRBD] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [PreviousRBDBeforUpdate] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [UPDATERBDFROMONEYEAAR] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [RBDbeforeupdatefromoneyear] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [TOBEADDEDFROM15DAYS] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [RBDBEFOREUPDATFROM15DAYS] [decimal](18, 8) NULL
)
```

The RbdTransaction will have the generated otps and the amount to be transferred from and to whom.

```
CREATE TABLE RbdTransaction
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    RBD Decimal (18,8),
    OTP Nvarchar(100),
    FromUserID bigint,
    ToUserID bigint,
    Active tinyint,
    CreatedDateTime Date
)
```

For the transaction of RBD from one table to another, I wrote a stored procedure as shown below.When I submit the necessary parameters, the stored procedure will check whether the RBD is available in the FromUsersID account in MainRBDBALANCE table and afterwards need to check the RbdTransaction table for the same then need to update both tables.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRBDTransactionMainRBDBalance (
    @OTP NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@FromUserID BIGINT
    ,@ToUserID BIGINT
    ,@RBD DECIMAL(18, 8)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM RbdTransaction
            WHERE OTP = @OTP
                AND FromUserID = @FromUserID
                AND ToUserID = @ToUserID
                AND RBD = @RBD
            )
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT TOP 1 1
                FROM hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
                WHERE USERID = @FromUserID
                    AND RBD >= @RBD
                )
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY
                BEGIN TRANSACTION

                UPDATE hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
                SET RBD = RBD - @RBD
                WHERE USERID = @FromUserID

                UPDATE RbdTransaction
                SET Active = 0
                WHERE OTP = @OTP
                    AND FromUserID = @FromUserID
                    AND ToUserID = @ToUserID
                    AND RBD = @RBD

                IF EXISTS (
                        SELECT TOP 1 1
                        FROM hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
                        WHERE USERID = @ToUserID
                        )
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
                    SET RBD = RBD - @RBD
                    WHERE USERID = @ToUserID
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE (
                        RBD
                        ,USERID
                        )
                    VALUES (
                        @RBD
                        ,@ToUserID
                        )
                END

                COMMIT TRANSACTION
            END TRY

            BEGIN CATCH
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            END CATCH
        END
    END
END
```

I need to use transaction because I need to update all tables simultaneously. Is this the correct way of doing transaction in sql server for my purpose.

Comment: It depends on what 'your purpose' is. A transaction means that is one if the statements within it fails, all the statements prior will rollback. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes that's what I want

Comment: I would be inclined to add `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERALIZABLE` to the start of that procedure. This will lock the tables for the duration of the transaction to prevent concurrent updates. As it stands there is a (very small) chance that two concurrent transactions could leave someone with a negative balance. I don't think making the transaction isolation level serializable will remove this chance completely, but it will reduce the chance

Comment: Ok I Update the same with SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERALIZABLE

Comment: Use `MERGE` not `EXISTS` as you let the DB work it out without risk of small windows for getting it wrong. And *don't* use `SERALIZABLE` unless it's a last resort.  It prevents concurrency and throughput.

Comment: @GarethD wouldn't the locks held by update statements remain for the duration of the transaction in read commited isolation level?

Comment: @SEarle1986 Yes, but the lock needs to be taken and held by the `SELECT` when doing the `NOT EXISTS` check. This is key to ensuring that a second transaction does not update the balance in the split second between checking the user has available funds and actually decreasing the balance. I have just realised that the transaction needs to start before this check in order for that to work though

Answer (score 2):

Your use of transactions is fine, however I would be inclined to change the way you check the balance here:

```
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
            WHERE USERID = @FromUserID
                AND RBD >= @RBD
            )
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            UPDATE hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
            SET RBD = RBD - @RBD
            WHERE USERID = @FromUserID
```

This leaves a small window of oppurtunity for the balance to change in between doing the check and the update. Instead, I would do the check at the same time as the update:

```
        UPDATE hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
        SET RBD = RBD - @RBD
        WHERE USERID = @FromUserID
        AND RBD >= @RBD;
```

You can then use `@@ROWCOUNT` to check if this updated any rows, if it did, then the user had available funds, if `@@ROWCOUNT` returns 0, this is the equivalent of failing the `EXISTS` check.

You can also remove the `EXISTS` check for the recipient account, and replace it with `MERGE`:

```
MERGE hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE AS t WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
USING (VALUES (@ToUserID)) AS s (UserID)
    ON t.userID = s.UserID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET RBD = RBD + @RBD
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (UserID, USERID) VALUES (s.UserID, @RBD);
```

This again removes the chance of a race condition resulting in duplicate users. The necessity for table locks to prevent a race condition is explained here - [“UPSERT” Race Condition With MERGE](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/01/31/upsert-race-condition-with-merge/)

So the final procedure would end up something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRBDTransactionMainRBDBalance (
    @OTP NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@FromUserID BIGINT
    ,@ToUserID BIGINT
    ,@RBD DECIMAL(18, 8)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM RbdTransaction
            WHERE OTP = @OTP
                AND FromUserID = @FromUserID
                AND ToUserID = @ToUserID
                AND RBD = @RBD
            )
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                UPDATE hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE
                SET RBD = RBD - @RBD
                WHERE USERID = @FromUserID
                AND RBD >= @RBD;

                IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE RbdTransaction
                    SET Active = 0
                    WHERE OTP = @OTP
                        AND FromUserID = @FromUserID
                        AND ToUserID = @ToUserID
                        AND RBD = @RBD;

                    MERGE hybarmoney.MAINRBDBALANCE AS t WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
                    USING (VALUES (@ToUserID)) AS s (UserID)
                        ON t.userID = s.UserID
                    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                        UPDATE SET RBD = RBD + @RBD
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                        INSERT (UserID, USERID) VALUES (s.UserID, @RBD);

                END

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END CATCH
    END
END
```

Comment: using `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` always results into non deterministic results, so i doubt the results off that query part. hard to verify if it is ok without example data and expected results

Comment: The only place `TOP 1` is used is in an `EXISTS` (where it is [not necessary at all](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/04/05/to-top-or-not-to-top-an-exists/), hence why I have removed it in my version), but even if it did something, it would not be relevant if the results are non-deterministic, it only matters that there is a result.

Comment: *"it would not be relevant if the results are non-deterministic, it only matters that there is a result. "* Very true, i think it's about coffee time as i didn't notice at first that was used in a `NOT EXISTS(...)`... As modern SQL optimizers in anny database nowadays should see that `NOT EXISTS(SELECT * .. )` or `NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 .. )` it should be executed in "boolean mode" meaning just checking of there is a result or not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not really keen on handling transactions inside the stored procedure because if you call from an application in which you manage transactions (which is a good practice) you will meet issues due this "double management"
So I would remove the TRY/CATCH and transaction management from the procedure and then call it like this :

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UpdateRBDTransactionMainRBDBalance (...);
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 1
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: I need to call this from an asp.net Button click even there I am not having any transaction.

Comment: You should !! On your db connection object, create a new transaction, then call your procedure and commit, all of this surrounded with a try/catch to rollback your transaction. Because as you do it, if an error occurs, no one will be warned as you hide the error by only rollback your transaction

Comment: Ok I will try that way

Comment: I disagree completely. In my opinion transactions should be handled in the stored procedure, and only in the application layer if necessary. For further reading on why I think this, the following answer pretty much sums up my opinion -  [Are we required to handle Transaction in C# Code as well as in stored procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93265/7257)

Comment: With this approach, you get an application in which some methods will manage transactions because you call more than 1 SP in it, and other that won't because they call only 1 procedure. Then, one day, you will need to add a new SP in your mono-SP transactionless method. So you wil start to implement the transaction in this method. It will be a real pleasure to check in the code that nobody forgot to manage the transaction in the right place ...